# Top Menu overlapping with the page content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

On the page - http://www.sugarkandy.com/category/electronics/ or for that matter any category page- the top menu is overlapping with the page contents.

As long as the number of categories in the top menu is less enough to keep it to a single line, it doesn;t interfere. As soon as I add some more categories in the top menu, it forms a new block ( away from the main logo- as shown currently) and starts overlapping the page contents.

How can I:
- Add more menu items ( categories) so that the menu doesn;t overlap with the page contents?
- How can I make sure that when the new categories are added, the menu doesn;t break off and does not start from the next line? I would rather have the menu items presented from next to the logo ( sugarkandy) itself ( as it happens when the menu items are less)?

Thanks.
I am not very well versed with html and css and hence get stuck at stupid issues. I explored and found that the z-index may be an issue, but could not find a way to improve that. Hence I am here.
Help would be appreciated.

-Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Your css line 27

```
media="all"
body {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: #444444;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
padding-top: 135px;  <----- THIS LINE CHANGE VALUE
height: 100%;
background: url(images/redox_01.png) repeat;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

seems like your theme is just not designed to work with more than 1 line of menu.

you can make the padding flexible by using jquery

```
$(function() {
  $('body').attr('padding-top',$('.navbar-inner').height()+'px');
}
```

Comment: Hi Vico, Thanks for the solution. But please pardon my handicap- how and where to add the function to make the padding flexible?

Comment: this is jquery script will have to go inside your footer.php or header within a script tag

Comment: Hi Vico,
I added the following in the header file:

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('body').attr('padding-top',$('.navbar-inner').height()+'px');
 });
  </script>

But it doesn;t work- no change to the menu. It still flows in multiple lines( which is fine) but is overlapping with the content( which is a big issue)

Sorry for troubling ya- any comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change only one word in the script.
the "attr" word ... please change it with "css"

old:

`$(function() {
  $('body').attr('padding-top',$('.navbar-inner').height()+'px');
}`

updated:
`$(function() {
  $('body').css('padding-top',$('.navbar-inner').height()+'px');
}`
I hope now you can see the difference.